# Creating\Updating conda venv with yml file fails in pip dependencies part with gym[rom]

Tags: pip, python-venv, openai-gym, miniconda, mamba

Im trying to create a virtual enviorment based on an enviorment.yml file with the command:
"mamba env update -f environment.yml -n cs236781-hw".

The yml file contains this part:

```
- pip:
  - nbmerge
  - gym[atari,accept-rom-license,box2d]==0.21.0
```

which seems to fail as I get this error in my minicinda prompt:

```
  Building wheel for AutoROM.accept-rom-license (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for AutoROM.accept-rom-license (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build AutoROM.accept-rom-license

Pip subprocess error:
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for AutoROM.accept-rom-license (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
```

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing libtorrent: The specified module could not be found.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for AutoROM.accept-rom-license
ERROR: Could not build wheels for AutoROM.accept-rom-license, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

Ive tried so many things to fix this (reinstalling conda, python even vscode and its c++ build tools)  with no success.
Does anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working on Windows x64?
If yes, you will probably need OpenSSL 1.1.x.

Please try to install e.g. Win64OpenSSL_Light-1_1_1s.exe first, to get the required SSL libraries.
https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Regards,
Konstantin